# calling Keras Model.evaluate() on every batch element separately

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I would like to call `tf.keras.Model.evaluate()` (or a similar method) on a batch of my test_data, and I would like to get back the losses/metrics separately for every batch **element**. So if the batches are 64 element long I would like back a list of 64 losses/metrics.

I need this in order to find outliers in the test dataset.

I tried calling test_on_batch(), or evaluate() on single batches, but this method aggregates the batch result (I assume via mean), and batching every element singularly, although possible, takes 10-20x the time on my GPU.

Also I tried to call predict() and calculate manually the losses/metrics, but this approach also suffers from a steep drop of performance (from the subsequent required manual step of calculating every loss/metric from the test dataset and the predictions)

Is there a way to do this without compromising performance?

Comment: which losses/metrics are involved in the evaluation?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani it's a very simple example on the mnist, so SparseCategoricalCrossentropy and SparseCategoricalAccuracy, but this shouldn't matter for the question right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the TensorFlow metric/loss function with `model.predict()` is fast and doesn't involve loops

considering this dummy classification task:

```
X = np.random.uniform(0,1, (64,28,28,1))
y = np.random.randint(0,2, 64)

model = Sequential([Flatten(), Dense(2, activation='softmax')])
model.compile('adam', 
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(), 
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])
model.fit(X,y, epochs=3)
```

you can evaluate the score **for every batch element** in this way:

```
scce = tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy(y, model.predict(X))
# scce.shape ==> (64,)

scca = tf.keras.metrics.sparse_categorical_accuracy(y, model.predict(X))
# scca.shape ==> (64,)
```

these scores are the same scores aggregated by `model.evaluate()`

```
scce_eval, scca_eval = model.evaluate(X,y, verbose=0)
```

`scce_eval` is equal to `tf.reduce_mean(scce)`

`scca_eval` is equal to `tf.reduce_mean(scca)`

Comment: Thanks @MarcoCerliani, this seems a great way to approach it. I was wondering, since I'm building an external library in which the score function could be different, or a composition of various metrics, if there was any way to calculate this without calling the single metrics/loss functions, since Keras already has all the information.

Comment: Is there a way to ask the keras model to return its current compiled loss function, or any of the other metrics that were compiled, for example?

Comment: I said u (in the comments) the metrics/loss involved for this reason... If you have your own custom loss/metric you have to write it without the mean reduction at the end. In this way, during fitting, a standard keras model will compute the mean reduction by itself, while in the evaluation u will be free to get the batch scores (using the same function) in the way I showed u... if u retain it valuable don't forget to upvote and accept as answer ;-)